# Transformar retorno Json em lista de objetos C#

Tags: c#, json

Tenho uma requisição para uma API que me retorna o seguinte JSON:

```
{"champions":[{"id":266,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":201,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":51,"active":true,"botEnabled":true,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":true,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":86,"active":true,"botEnabled":true,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":true,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":74,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":222,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":55,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":64,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":111,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":76,"active":true,"botEnabled":true,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":true,"rankedPlayEnabled":true},{"id":112,"active":true,"botEnabled":false,"freeToPlay":true,"botMmEnabled":false,"rankedPlayEnabled":true}]}
```

Possuo a seguinte classe:

```
public class Champions
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool BotEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Como eu faço para transformar o retorno Json em uma `List<Champions>` ?

Comment: Conseguiu?      .......

Comment: A classe devia chamar-se `Champion` e não `Champions`.

Comment: Pq essa mudança sendo que o retorno está como `champions` ?

Comment: @JonathanBarcela alguma resposta abaixo resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte.

```
public class ChampionsList
{
    public List<Champions> Champions { get; set; }  
}

public class Champions
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "BotEnabled")]
    public bool BotEnabled { get; set; }
}

[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod()]
public void LoadChampions(String RespJson)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        var ChampionsList = js.Deserialize<ChampionsList>(RespJson);

        foreach (var c in ChampionsList.Champions)
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Tá montando uma lista vazia, sendo que no Json tem 11 objetos.

Comment: Alterei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a dll Newtonsoft tenta assim:

```
public IEnumerable<Champions> LoadChampions(string json)
{ 
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Champions>>(json);
}
```